# Surjectivity of linear transformation over an infinite dimensional Vectorspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $W$ be the complex vectorspace of all functions from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$.
$T:W \to W$ defined as $f\mapsto T(f)$ with $T(f)(t):=f(t+\frac{1}{2})$ for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

**Prove that:**

1. $T$ is a linear transformation.
2. $T$ is bijective.

---

To show that $T$ is indeed linear we need to show that $T(f+\lambda g)=T(f)+\lambda T(g)$ for every $t$, so I wrote:  $$T(f+\lambda g)(t)=(f+\lambda g)(t+\frac{1}{2})=f(t+\frac{1}{2})+\lambda g(t+\frac{1}{2})=T(f)(t)+\lambda T(g)(t)$$
My argument for injectivity, feels a bit handwavy however.
Let $f$ be an element of the kernel of $T$: $$T(f)=f(t+\frac{1}{2})=0$$ Since $f(t+\frac{1}{2})$ has to be  $0$ for every $t$ it follows that $f$ can only be the zero function and thus the kernel is trivial. Is that a valid argument? Whats left to show is the surjectivity of $T$. Here I don't know how to proceed since $W$ is of infinite dimension. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$ then $f(t)=g(t-\frac1 2 )$ defines another function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$ and we have $Tf=g$. Hence, $T$ is surjective. Your argument for injectivity is valid.

Comment: Neat and simple, thankyou!